# Can't access careers profile after creation by using 'Try github...'

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I get a 'Oops! Something Bad Happened!' page when trying to view my profile on Careers. The profile was created by using the 'Try github...' feature.

There are a lot of similar issues reported here on meta, and it seems they are all resolved. Perhaps my bug has got something to do with the fact the profile was created by accessing github?

Comment: It seems to be fixed now ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, this should be resolved.